# Use PrimeFaces Showcase theme or similar in application

Tags: jsf, primefaces, themes

PrimeFaces Showcase's components look and feel look pretty nice and simple.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But in my application, using the default theme or any other theme provided by PrimeFaces (Nova-Light, Nova-Dark, Luna-Blue, ...), the components don't look nice (at least in my opinion, of course). They have some kind of 3D look with shadows inside inputs, for example. I really don't like it.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

I understand that maybe this is a matter of taste, but I really would like to have the same theme (or at last something similar) to the PrimeFaces Showcase theme in my application. Is there a theme for this or do I have to struggle with CSS?

Comment: That looks like the default `Aristo` theme.  That is not what Nova-Light looks like as Nova-Light is used by the current showcase so your components should look like that if you set the Theme correctly in `web.xml`

Comment: I changed the theme to `nova-light` and it seems to have worked, althought components now looks a little big. Maybe I have just to apply some CSS to fix the components size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current online showcase uses 'nova-light' theme, just like documented in the official documentation: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/themes

Comment: Changed to `nova-light` and it worked, although the components look a little big now, bigger than the PrimeFaces Showcase. Maybe I have to use CSS now to fix the sizes.

Comment: Yep you probably have to tweak your CSS.

Comment: @Melloware It's already done, but it wasn't too much work.